# How to add examples to an SBT project?

Tags: scala, sbt, project-structure

I want to add some examples to my Scala library. I prefer a directory layout like this:

```
examples/
    example1/
        Main.scala
        ...
    example2/
        Main.scala
        ...
src/
    main/
        scala/
            ...
    test/
        scala/
            ...
build.sbt
```

The examples use the packages in `src/main/scala/`. Is it possible to build and run the examples using SBT? Is it also possible to have dependencies specific to the examples?

Comment: You might want to make examples a "sub-project" which depends on the main project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but you likely have to resort to complete .scala definition. [I've put example project on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/omnomnom/example-of-examples).

Here is the showcase:

```
// [info] Loading global plugins from /Users/omnomnom/.sbt/0.13/plugins
// [info] Loading project definition from /Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/project
// [info] Set current project to root-project (in build file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/)
> projects
// [info] In file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/
// [info]      example1
// [info]      example2
// [info]    * root-project
> project example1
// [info] Set current project to example1 (in build file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/)
> run
// [info] Updating {file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/}root-project...
// [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
// [info] Done updating.
// [info] Updating {file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/}example1...
// [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
// [info] Done updating.
// [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/target/scala-2.10/classes...
// [info] Running Main 
I'm example #1
// [success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jul 4, 2014 10:17:54 PM
> project example2
// [info] Set current project to example2 (in build file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/)
> run
// [info] Updating {file:/Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/}example2...
// [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
// [info] Done updating.
// [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/omnomnom/projects/example-of-examples/examples/example2/target/scala-2.10/classes...
// [info] Running Main 
I'm example #2
// [success] Total time: 3 s, completed Jul 4, 2014 10:18:04 PM
```

And Build.scala, just for the case:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Build extends Build {

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xlint"),
    organization := "me.lazyval",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
    initialCommands in console := "import me.lazyval._"
  )

  // altering source path, since you don't want to replicate usual src/main ... stuff
  val exampleSourcePath = scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "."

  lazy val root = Project(id = "root-project", base = file("."), settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ settings)

  lazy val example1 = Project(id = "example1", base = file("./examples/example1"), settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ settings ++ Seq(exampleSourcePath)) dependsOn root
  // in `settings= ...` section you can set whatever dependencies you like 
  lazy val example2 = Project(id = "example2", base = file("./examples/example2"), settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ settings ++ Seq(exampleSourcePath)) dependsOn root
}
```

Comment: As of sbt 0.13, you can define `val`s, `lazy val`s and sub-projects in a `build.sbt`. You do not need a `Build.scala`. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html

Comment: @sjrd cool, didn't knew this (I was avoiding using 0.13 in general because of the some bugs it has)